# SED/AWK Chunk Firstname From FULL NAME

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have fields with data

```
ROLL_NO|NAME|AGE

001|MR. Kevin Piterson|18
002|Miss. Maria Sharapova|20
010|Shaun|20
```

My expected output is

```
001|MR. Kevin|18
002|Miss. Maria|20
010|Shaun|20
```

I am gazed thinking how can I get data [Confused on REGEX]
AWK or SED ?

What I was trying so Far is

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" }
{
    n = split($2,name,/[ ]/)
    $2 = name[1] name[2]

}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/ [^ ]*|/|/' file
```

Output:

```
001|MR. Kevin|18
002|Miss. Maria|20
010|Shaun|20
```

If you want to edit your file "in place", add sed's option `-i`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you also help me in my logic which I have tried as well

Comment: Sorry, I'm an awk newbie.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ [^ |]*|/|/' file


awk -F '|' -vOFS='|' '{sub(/ [^ ]*$/,"",$2)}1' file
```

You Code:

try this

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" }
{
    n = split($2,name,/[ ]/)
    $2 = name[2]?name[1]" "name[2]:name[1]

}1'
```

Comment: Thanks.. Let me check the solutions

Comment: But what about the header?

Comment: Header was just to make things clear about the data. actual data doesn't have those values

Answer (score 0):

By using awk default separator space to remove column 3 "$3" the family names gets removed.

```
awk '{sub($3,"")}' file
    001|MR. Kevin |18
    002|Miss. Maria |20
    010|Shaun|20
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I use `awk` script to get ("MR. " or "Miss. ") and first name. Please see below.

This is data file.

```
$cat data
001|MR. Kevin Piterson|18
002|Miss. Maria Sharapova|20
010|Shaun|20
```

This is awk script file.

```
$cat src.awk
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS = "|"
  OFS = "|"
}

{
  # Get (MR. or Miss. ) first name
  if(match($2, /^(MR\. |Miss\. )?[^ ]+/)) {
    print($1, substr($2, RSTART, RLENGTH), $3)
  }
}
```

This is result.

```
$./src.awk data
001|MR. Kevin|18
002|Miss. Maria|20
010|Shaun|20
```